# Trying to count letter frequency in text file in Python

Tags: python, string, object, readlines

I have a program that will count the letters in a specific text file, (In my example, "Words.txt"). However, when I try to change the code to accept user input instead of looking for a specific file, I get the following:-
'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'

I am sure it is something really sill that I am doing, but I cannot see why. My code is below:

```
import string
#fname=raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fname=open('words.txt', 'r')

#if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "words.txt"
file_list = fname.readlines()

freqs = dict()
for line in file_list:
line = filter(lambda x: x in string.letters, line.lower())
for char in line:
    if char in freqs:
        freqs[char] += 1
    else:
        freqs[char] = 1
lst = list()
for key, val in freqs.items():
  lst.append( (val, key) )

lst.sort(reverse=True)

for key, val in lst[:] :
    print key, val
```

Comment: You want to call readlines() on user inout

Comment: `fname` is not a good name for a file object. Do not confuse files with file names.

Answer (score 1):

What you get from `raw_input` is just a string holding the *name* of the file. You still have to `open` it to get an actual file handle.

```
filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fname = open(filename, 'r')
```

Also, you might want to use `with` so that the file is automatically closed at the end of the execution. And instead of reading all the lines into a list, you can just iterate the file directly.

```
filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
with open(filename, 'r') as fname:
    freqs = dict()
    for line in fname:
        ...
```

Finally, you might take a look at [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fname = open(fname, 'r')
```

Two additional pieces of advice:

1) Use the `with` statement when handling files (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

2) No need to store all the lines in file_list, just iterate over the file object

```
filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
with open(filename, 'r') as fil:
    for line in fil:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `readlines()` can only be called on a file input. The equivalent of this on a user-input (which is a string), would be `splitlines()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the user to provide a filename (as mentioned in other answers that came in while I was providing more details), you just need to do:

```
fname=raw_input("Enter file name")
file_list = open(fname).readlines()
```

If you want the user to enter the data, you can do
`file_list = sys.stdin.readlines()`

Also note that the preferred way to process files is with "with"

```
with open("x.txt") as f:
    for line in f: 
       #process each line
```

This handles closing the file when you're done and also allows you to treat f as an iterator (so you can read each line in as needed versus reading it all in at once)

Lastly, if you did want to read from stdin or from files, under Unix-y Operating Systems at least, you could use the sys.stdin.readlines bit above and if you want to read from a file do `python myprogram.py < filename`